# specifying function as the event handler for button

Tags: javascript, html

how can i specify function record (which is in item.js file)as the event handler for onclick event for "b1" button
with in the following javascript

item.html-------------------

```
<body>

<form>
<input type = "button" id="b1" value = "click" />
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">

----code should be here------

</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
<input type = "button" id="b1" value = "click" onclick="functionHere();" />
```

Therefore the Javascript is immediately applied instead of when the code is reached (as in gilly's example).

Gilly's example is also good, but this is just a different method.

Comment: @Abdullah , i know this method which u shown but i needed the gilly method. thanks

Comment: @Abdullah thanks for giving me credit.  But isn't javascript: necessary before the function for some browsers since not all will recognize what it is?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need it for event handlers but opened up a question just in case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876452/when-is-javascript-needed

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
document.getElementById("b1").onclick = record;
```

Comment: thank u so much for ur help. this site is really very useful in solving problems.u people doing great job

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#b1').click(record);
});
```