# When is "javascript: ..." needed?

Tags: javascript

Is the `javascript:` prefix really needed? I know you should aim for unobtrusive JavaScript but under what circumstances would something break if it is not there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372159/do-you-ever-need-to-specify-javascript-in-an-onclick

Comment: @Demian: Highly related but I'm not sure that they're "exact" duplicates.

Comment: @Demian, thanks for that link, interesting that it may just be a simple label in an onclick/event handler definition.

Comment: @tomalak: Yeah, wasn't sure - wanted to point the OP to pre-existing answers on a similar thread though :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`javascript:` is a URI scheme.

It is needed to create a URI that runs Javascript, either in an `href=""` attribute or in the browser address bar.
There is never a situation in which `javascript:` is optional.

Best practices indicate that `javascript:` URIs should be avoided where possible in favor of `click` handlers, so its use is frowned upon.

However, there are cases where there is no alternative.  For example, bookmarklets can only be created by using `javascript:`.

Comment: So does this mean that in the onclick attribute they are also necessary?

Comment: @Flipper: **No**.  The only reason it works in `onclick` is that it happens to be valid Javascript syntax (a `goto` label).  `onclick` isn't a URI.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372159/do-you-ever-need-to-specify-javascript-in-an-onclick

Answer (score 1):

They're "needed" if you are encoding Javascript code into an URI, for example in the `href` property of an `<a>` tag.

[They're bad practice, though.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479557/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-use-links-with-the-javascript-protocol)

Answer (score 0):

If you put JavaScript code into the `href` attribute of an `a`, or other attribute which takes a URL, then it's required for the browser to detect that it is JS. It's not necessary (and may not even work) if you use it with `onclick` or other attributes that already expect JS code.

Answer (score 0):

That "prefix" is used only in the href attribute of an html anchor (). It is never actually needed, since you could as well define a click event handler.

Answer (score 0):

It is needed even in onclick situations if you also have a VBS routine on the same page.